# php как посчитать количество созданных объектов на странице, как зарегистрировать общий деструктор для всех классов\объектов

Tags: php

Хочу посчитать количество создаваемых\созданных объектов на странице. Думаю если возможно то в общем деструкторе для всех объектов (если такой можно сделать) делать

```
$_SESSION['cou_obj']=$_SESSION['cou_obj']+1;
```

Но как общий деструктор зарегистрировать? Или как-то по другому можно посчитать кол-во объектов?

Объект - это то что получается после (или в результате использования) **new**

**upd1** Я заканчиваю допереписывание сайта вна ООП. Стало интересно сколько объектов на каждой конкретной странице создается.

Объекты создаются только ... (абсолютно весь сайт!) на php, при помощи `new`.

Дело в том что не в каждом классе есть конструктор.

Мне уже понаподсказывали что можно попробовать каким-то профайлером, отладчиком...

Какие такие объекты?: ну вот например такие

```
    $vld = new Validator();
    $ust = new UserStatus();
    $rd = new Redirect();
    $e = new Err();
    $tr = new TrimTxt();
    $all_user_tags = new AllUserTags($uid);
    $user_logins = new UserLogins();
    $global_posts_search = new GlobalPostsSearch();
```

Самих классов примерно до 200 штук.
И желательно посчитать без тяжких изменений кода - вот потому я и подумал что вдруг можно сделать деструктор общий для всех классов\объектов.

**upd2** Зачем я занимаюсь такой "ерундой": Как-то где-то читал что в древних версиях можно было создавать (например!) 1 000 объектов, в свежих версиях можно создавать 10 000 объектов, а версии phpp 8 можно создавать 100 000 объектов...

Разве никто никогда не интересовался количеством создаваемых объектов на странице???

Вот потому и интересно мне сколько у меня. Может у меня десятки или сотни тысяч объектов создается? Тогда такой код назвать хорошим нельзя. Хотя код, **во-первых**, предназначен только для чтения и понимания человеком-программистом.

Есть вариант после каждого `new` делать

```
  $_SESSION['cou_obj']++;
```

Наверное так и сделаю, хотя и будет небольшая заморочка с этим, но думаю что `sed` поможет мне в этом.

Как еще можно посчитать объекты?

---

**И может в php9 появится возможность задавать один деструктор для всех объектов?**

Comment: звучит как будто речь должна идти о конструкторе, а не деструкторе. вы лучше опишите задачу, которую вы решаете? Что за объекты и как создаются? юзер посредством аякса это делает, или что?

Comment: @teran , я дополнил +описание ЗАЧЕМ мне это.

Comment: про "100, 1000 и 10000" - это чушь собачья. какой-то фантазер высосал из пальца. от версии количество не зависит. Ради просто удовлетворения любопытства тратить время на эту ерунду глупо. про пхп 9 сейчас неизвестно вообще ничего, но опять же, вероятность, что кто-то будет заниматься этой ерундой стремится к нулю. Если интересует производительность, то нужен профайлер. Если код работает быстро, то считать объектики бессмысленно. Если медленно - то надо искать почему, а не считать объектики

Comment: @Ипатьев , со скоросью всё в хорошо. и я еще буду тестировать с ограничением быстродействия (и сервера и клиента) в виртуалках.  Каждый более-менее непростой запрос к бд - на этапе создания самого запроса, проверлся при помощи `explain`. Но ведь мне очень интересно! А по поводу 1000, 10000 .. где-то я видел похожую картинку https://www.php.net/manual/en/images/12f37b1c6963c1c5c18f30495416a197-gc-benchmark.png но там был график: версии php, и количество объектов... Прям сейчас не могу найти где именно я видел такой график.

Comment: @Ипатьев, "Ради просто удовлетворения любопытства тратить время на эту ерунду глупо" - не успокоюсь, пока не узнаю. ;%:)))

Comment: Этот график - заведомая чушь. Вот можно самому убедиться, меняя версии https://phpize.online/?phpses=f657f31668432a96107561976c41813a

Comment: И нет, get_defined_vars не поможет, поскольку считает только пременные в текущей области видимости

Comment: @Ипатьев "get_defined_vars не поможет," - при чем тут get_defined_vars ? Я про команду `sed` https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed и про автоматическую вставку после строчки с `new`, строки `$_SESSION['cou_obj']++; `.

Comment: @Ипатьев "Этот график - заведомая чушь." - Я не конкретно об этом графике!, я видел похожий график. но где он сейчас не могу вспомнить\найти. Выше... `где-то` **я видел похожую картинку** `php.net/manual/en/images/… но там был график: версии php, и количество объектов... Прям сейчас не могу найти где именно я видел такой график.`

Comment: вы комментарии вообще читаете? или только пишете? что неясно в коде, который выполняется по ссылке?

Comment: Может попробуйте что-то типа XDebug?

Answer (score 1):

1. Новые объекты создаются не только c помощью `new`, но и при клонировании (`clone $obj`), десериализации(`unserialize()`,`json_decode()` и т.д) и приведении (`(object) [...]`) и не всегда конструктор/деструктор вызывается при этом.
2. Предопределённые классы php и расширений также могут не вызывать  конструктор/деструктор при создании объектов.
3. Статический анализ кода слишком сложен ввиду многообразия вариантов.
4. Наследование/примеси проблематично реализовать по тем же причинам.

В теории можно отслеживать создание классов с помощью `xdebug`:

```php
xdebug_start_function_monitor(['DateTime->__construct', 'Exception->__construct', 'MyClass->__construct']);
$date = new DateTime();
$obj = new MyClass();
$_SESSION['objects'] = xdebug_get_function_count();
// var_dump(xdebug_get_monitored_functions());
xdebug_stop_function_monitor();
```

или `uopz`:

```php
uopz_set_hook('Exception', '__construct', function () {$_SESSION['objects']++;});
```

но эти варианты не срабатывают для некоторых предопределённых классов ( например, `stdClass`).
Как вариант можно попробовать профилирование с помощью расширений `xdebug` или `xhprof`.

Comment: У меня объекты создаются только по `new`. Я еще не решил как проще сделать этот\такой подсчёт.

Comment: @Aliskin Cторонние пакеты/фреймворки не используются? если нет, то подойдет вариант `xdebug_*_function_monitor()`. Cписок нативных классов php придется создавать вручную, а пользователькие можно добавлять при автозагрузке ( `spl_autoload_register()`).

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант, если объекты создаются только по `new` (способ не учтет то что указано в ответе WinterSilence в п.1):

через IDE или текстовый редактор (например phpStorm, notepad++) сделать массовую замену по регулярному выражению:

Ищем `(new .*\(.*\);)`

Заменяем на `$1\$_SESSION['cnt']++;`

И в конце выводим `$_SESSION['cnt']`. Либо можно в файле который подключается при любом запросе объявить `register_shutdown_function` с выводом количества.

Comment: ага, и так по всему каталогу vendor

Comment: судя по приведенному примеру классов никакого vendor там нет) но я указал что это совсем не универсальный способ, о регулярках до меня тут пока никто не говорил. автор уж сам решит применим ли способ в его проекте и как

Comment: @Maximmka , да у меня нет ничего стандартного. Вопрос не решен. но ваш ответ схож с тем что первым пришло мне в голову. После каждого 'new' делать +1 к переменной. В конце страницы делать вывод этой переменной. Только для этого я применять `sed`